# How to remove percentages and horizontal lines inside a bar chart in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to remove the horizontal line inside the bar plot in my codes as well as the %. I only would like to keep the percentages on top of each bar not inside, however, I could not fix it. Any help and also improvement in the graph is highly appreciated. I tried the codes above, but the graph has still problem and I need help to fix it.

```
data <- data.frame(
  Variables = c(rep("A", 5), rep("B", 5), rep("C", 5), rep("D", 5), rep("E", 2),
                rep("F", 5), rep("G", 5), rep("H", 5), rep("I", 5), rep("J", 5)),
  Categories = c("Always", "Often", "Occasionally", "Rarely", "Never",
                 "Always", "Often", "Occasionally", "Rarely", "Never",
                 "Very effective", "Effective", "Neutral", "Ineffective", "Very ineffective",
                 "Always", "Often", "Occasionally", "Rarely", "Never",
                 "Yes", "No",
                 "Strongly agree", "Agree", "Neutral", "Disagree", "Strongly disagree",
                 "Very effective", "Effective", "Neutral", "Ineffective", "Very ineffective",
                 "Strongly agree", "Agree", "Neutral", "Disagree", "Strongly disagree",
                 "Very engaged", "Engaged", "Neutral", "Disengaged", "Very disengaged",
                 "Very likely", "Likely", "Neutral", "Unlikely", "Very unlikely"),
  Frequency_percent = c(8, 3, 1, 0, 0,
                        0, 9, 2, 1, 0,
                        0, 10, 2, 0, 0,
                        0, 10, 1, 0, 1,
                        11, 1,
                        9, 2, 1, 0, 0,
                        10, 1, 1, 0, 0,
                        7, 4, 1, 0, 0,
                        6, 5, 1, 0, 0,
                        4, 5, 3, 0, 0),
  percent = c(67, 25, 8, 0, 0,
              0, 75, 16,8, 0,
              0, 83, 17, 0, 0,
              0, 84, 8, 0, 8,
              92, 8,
              75, 17, 8, 0, 0,
              84, 8, 8, 0, 0,
              59, 33, 8, 0, 0,
              50, 42, 8, 0, 0,
              33, 42, 25, 0, 0)
  
)

data_long <- gather(data, key = "Frequency", value = "percent", -Variables, -Categories)


label_mapping <- data.frame(
  Original_Labels = unique(data_long$Variables),
  Short_Labels = LETTERS[1:length(unique(data_long$Variables))]
)


data_long_mapped <- merge(data_long, label_mapping, by.x = "Variables", by.y = "Original_Labels")


data_filtered <- data_long_mapped[data_long_mapped$percent > 0, ]


ggplot(data_filtered, aes(x = Short_Labels, y = percent, fill = Categories)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", color = "black") +
  labs(title = "Student Responses",
       x = "Variables",
       y = "%",
       fill = NULL) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 0.5),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color = "black"),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "bottom") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Categories")) +  # Added a legend title
  geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = 1), vjust = -0.5, size = 3, color = "black", aes(label = ifelse(percent > 0, paste0(percent, "%"), "")))`
`
```

Comment: The issue is that you are plotting both the absolute (column `Frequency_percent` in your orig. data) and relative frequencies (column `percent` in your orig. data). Hence you get two bars and two labels. Filter your long data for your desired value and you should be fine, e.g. `data_filtered_filtered <- subset(data_filtered, Frequency == "percent")`

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that fixes both issues. As @stefan mentioned filtering the data fixes the labeling issue. Adding the below code to `theme()` will remove the grid lines.

```
panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
```

Here is some complete code (using @stefan's suggestion) for the graph:

```
data_filtered_filtered <- subset(data_filtered, Frequency == "percent")

ggplot(data_filtered_filtered, aes(x = Short_Labels, y = percent, fill = Categories)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", color = "black") +
  labs(title = "Student Responses",
       x = "Variables",
       y = "%",
       fill = NULL) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 0.5),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color = "black"),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Categories")) +  # Added a legend title
  geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = 1), vjust = -0.5, size = 3, color = "black", aes(label = ifelse(percent > 0, paste0(percent, "%"), "")))
```